# error itms-90122 - invalid executable size

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, adobe

I just have some problems uploading my app to the appstore.
The problem is the 60MB filesizelimit for armv7! (See Screenshot)

There are almost no embedded images or something like that.
the application-file is only 0,5MB to big, but I'm sure it will increase soon due to next updates

Are there any possibilities to reduce the application size? Or maybe to change some settings for excluding the armv7 and only build for 64bit?

Our App is online since a couple of years and now we got "too big"?   I see no possibility to "reduce" the code.

I build with AIR 22 and compiler options "-optimize=true -strict=true"

[image]

Comment: Here is my iOS part of app.xml:

`<iPhone>
  <InfoAdditions>
   <![CDATA[
   <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
   <array>
    <string>2</string>
   </array>
   <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
   <true/>
   <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
         <string>8.0</string>       
  ]]>
  </InfoAdditions>
  <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>


  <Entitlements>
   <![CDATA[
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>beta-reports-active</key>
    <true/>
   ]]>
  </Entitlements>


 </iPhone>`

Answer (score 7):

There's 2 ways.

The first is make your binary under 60MB.
2nd way is setting up project deployment target number.

ths following is I received email from Apple DTS

There are a few approaches to solving this situation:

1. Look through the suggestions in Q&A 1795, Reducing the size of my app. The section on compiler options is relevant for your scenario. Also, if you have data in your binary, such as long strings, tables, or encoded images, you should move those resources out of your binary and into external files.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html
2. The 60 MB limit is per architecture in your main executable. Identify sections of your app that would make sense as either a single framework, or as a small number of frameworks, so that they are built into a different binary.
3. If your app’s minimum deployment can be raised to iOS 9, the limit on executable size is higher, up to 400 MB for the entire executable.  This is described at the link below.
   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: Broken link, here is the updated docs:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev611e0a21f