# How to resize xamarin iOS app for arm64 architectures to 60MB?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, deployment

I want to deploy my new app, but he is 178MB and I receive this error from xCode:

```
ERROR ITMS-90122: "Invalid Executable Size. The size of your app's executable file 'WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS' is 81592320 bytes for architecture 'arm64', which exceeds the maximum allowed size of 60 MB."
```

My pictures is 2MB and all the code is no more than 2000 lines ?

How can I resize my app ?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own to solve this?  There are hundreds of existing questions here and elsewhere on the web about this topic.

Comment: Can you give me a hyperlink, please ?

Comment: oh yeah how I hadn't thought of it before, a great solution to the problem !

Comment: there is no indication in your post that you have done any research or attempted anything to fix this yourself.  The very first topic in [ask] is "Search and Research"

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541755/8335151) is an answer to handle "Invalid Executable Size".  It points out how to reduce the app size or update to iOS9+.